# Case statement in Update query based on Row data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following structure:

```
ID int (primary key)
SectionName varchar(50)
Allowed bit
```

For example there are 5 sections:

```
ID   SectionName     Allowed
-----------------------------
1    Basement          1
2    First Floor       1
3    Second Floor      1
4    Third Floor       1
5    Parking           1
```

I have a C# application that will call a stored procedure with the following parameters populated

```
@Basement = false
@First_Floor = true
@Second_Floor = true
@Third_Floor = false
@Parking = true
```

After I executed the result of the stored procedure, I would like the values to look like

```
ID   SectionName     Allowed
----------------------------
1    Basement          0
2    First Floor       1
3    Second Floor      1
4    Third Floor       0
5    Parking           1
```

How would I create this stored procedure in Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: What have you tried? Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Added extra line to answer your questions @jarlh

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a boolean type, so your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: You understood what boolean means... obviously its a bit so not sure what you mean by doesn't make sense

Comment: For what it's worth, the Too Broad close reason is often employed for questions of the form "I have no idea where to start". People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [**Where to Start**](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), then address your post if you think that it should be reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case could be as

```
case 
    when sectionName = 'Basement' then iif(@Basement = true, 1,0) 
    when sectionName = 'First Floor' then iif(@First_Floor = true, 1,0)         
    when sectionName = 'Second Floor' then iif(@Second_Floor = true, 1,0) 
    when sectionName = 'Third Floor' then iif(@Third_Floor = true, 1,0) 
    when sectionName = 'Parking' then iif(@Parking = true, 1,0) 
end
```

and you could use an update

```
update your_table  
set allowed =   case 
        when sectionName = 'Basement' then iif(@Basement = true, 1,0) 
        when sectionName = 'First Floor' then iif(@First_Floor = true, 1,0)         
        when sectionName = 'Second Floor' then iif(@Second_Floor = true, 1,0) 
        when sectionName = 'Third Floor' then iif(@Third_Floor = true, 1,0) 
        when sectionName = 'Parking' then iif(@Parking = true, 1,0) 
    end
```

Comment: It does not like the if. says incorrect syntax

Comment: @sciasEdge the if is underlined red by the intelisence and the message is just "Incorrect syntax near 'if'"

Comment: Ok that took away the error will test now

Answer (score 1):

you can try like below

```
update table
set allowed= case when SectionName in ('Basement','Third Floor') then 0
                    else 1 end
```

Answer (score 1):

use `case when expression`

```
update tablename set allowed=case when sectionName in ('Basement','Third Floor') then 0 else
1 end
```

Comment: this seems like a very static query not using the Basement = false
First_Floor = true
Second_Floor = true
Third_Floor = false
Parking = true

Comment: I find it a bit odd that fa06 and Zaynul Abadin Tuhin so often have very similar answers. Room mates?

Comment: Both accounts from same place, same title, almost same start date etc... And same answers, upvotes etc...

Comment: @jarlh  a little bit more stat zaynul Answered  so far (1,767) but fa06 answered 1349 zaynul member for 2yr 6m and fa06 2yr5m and i think our mac address is also different :P